# How can I wrap the value of json with curly braces?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, lodash

Let say I have json like this (use JSON.stringify)

> { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith'}

And I want the value wrapped with curly braces like this

> { name: { value: 'Bill' }, lastname: { value: 'Smith'} }

So any idea to do like this using javascript or lodash?

Comment: Can I know the reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `Object.entries` on the input, map to a nested object, then call `Object.fromEntries` to transform it back again:

```js
const input = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith'};
const newObj = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(input).map(
    ([key, value]) => ([key, { value }])
  )
);
console.log(newObj);
```

`Object.fromEntries` is a pretty new method, so for older browsers, either include a polyfill or use something like `.reduce` instead:

```js
const input = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith'};
const newObj = Object.entries(input).reduce(
  (a, [key, value]) => {
    a[key] = { value };
    return a;
  },
  {}
);
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the keys of the object using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and update it like this:

```js
const input = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith'};

for (const key in input) {
  input[key] = { value: input[key] }
}

console.log(input)
```

If you don't want to mutate the input and want to create a new object, then create another object and update it:

```js
const input = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith'},
      output = {}

for (const key in input) {
  output[key] = { value: input[key] }
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) to return a new object with transformed values:

```js
const object = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith'};

const result = _.mapValues(object, value => ({ value }));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```