# How can I wrap the value of json with curly braces including child array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Base on this post [How can I wrap the value of json with curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895963/how-can-i-wrap-the-value-of-json-with-curly-braces)

how about append "value" in nested structure?

> { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith',   child: {
>           name: 'Adam',
>           options: [{
>                      option: "1"
>                    },
>                    { option: "2"
>                    }]
>           } }

and the result should be

```
{ name: { value:'Bill'}, lastname: { value:'Smith'},
  child: {
        name: { value:'Adam'},
        options: [{
                  option: { value:'1'}
                 },
                 { option: { value:'2'}
                 }]
        }
        ... 
}
```

Comment: This is almost the same question as the one you've asked before. Have you tried applying the answers there to get the results you want? What problems did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

Run through it recursively and add special treatment for arrays and objects.

```js
const input = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith', child: { name: 'Adam', options: [{ option: "1" }, { option: "2" }] } };
const transform = (input) => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(input).map(([key, value]) => {
    // If it is an array, transform each object in it
    if(Array.isArray(value)) {
      return ([key, value.map(el => transform(el))]); 
    } 
    // If it is an object, transform its value
    else if(typeof value === 'object' && value !== null)  {
      return [key, transform(value)]; 
    }
    // If it is a normal value, add the {value: } part
    else {
      return ([key, { value }]); 
    }
  })
);

console.log(transform(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive function which is called for every property in your object.

```js
var arr = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith', child: { name: 'Adam', options: [{ option: "1" }, { option: "2" }] } };

function translate(obj) {
  for (var property in obj){
    if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
      obj[property] = translate(obj[property]);
    }
    else{
      obj[property] = {value: obj[property]}
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(translate(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function with lodash's `_.transform()` that iterates objects and arrays, and wraps other types of properties with `value`:

```js
const fn = obj => _.transform(obj, (acc, value, k) => {
  acc[k] = _.isObject(value) ? fn(value): { value }
})

const data = { name: 'Bill', lastname: 'Smith', child: { name: 'Adam', options: [{ option: "1" }, { option: "2" }] } }

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```